# How to format Google Places Autocomplete text pushed into textbox

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm using Google places AutoComplete on a textbox and it's essentially working, picking the locations and stuffing them into the textboxes.

The problem is that I want to only stuff the selection name - not the full name + address formatting out of the list that the AutoComplete list produces. I can't seem to find a way to override what goes into the textbox.

```
    var $name = $("#txtName");
    $name.focus();

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($name[0]);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        // explicitly update model
        // but doesn't display in UI
        $scope.locationData.Name = place.name;


        // explicitly update the input box - doesn't update UI
        $name.val(place.name);

        return false;  // doesn't work - updates UI
    });
```

Basically what I'd like to do is take over the input box text assignment myself by doing the assignment myself and forcing autocomplete to not set the textbox value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Set the value with a short delay.

```
$('#NameBox').on('blur change', function () { $(this).val(place.name).off('blur change'); });
setTimeout(function () { $('#NameBox').val(place.name); }, 150);
```

Using `.off()` allows the user to edit the name if they wish. If you wish to only allow the places API name remove `.off()`.